# Link in UIAlertView's text

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4

I have a `UIAlertView` with **a very long text** that I put in the "**message:**" parameter of the alert. Because the text is very long, the alert displays it as a textview, and it's good.

The problem is that I have **2 URLs** in the text, and I want to give the user **the ability to click** them in the text and go out to the safari app.

I've tried using a **custome textview** and adding it to the alert as a subview but because the text is very long, *it causes few problems*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that I have 2 URLs in the text, and I want to give the user the ability to click them in the text and go out to the safari app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've added a UIWebview and loaded a html file I created locally.